# html5 canvas drawing not getting recognised

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, draw

I'm trying to create a simple html 5 canvas however it looks as if my JavaScript is not returning the right thing:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>

<script>
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
console.log(c);
// var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
// ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
// ctx.fillRect(0,0,150,75);
</script>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="100"
style="border:1px solid #000000;">
</canvas>

</body>
</html>
```

My console log returns a null even though that element exists. I have checked and my browser does support 2d graphics and canvas.

Comment: Because you are not waiting for the page to load before executing the script the script block is being parsed and executed before the canvas is even seen. Put your canvas block before the script block and your code will execute as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="100" style="border:1px solid #000000;"></canvas>
<script>
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
console.log(c);
</script>
```

**NOTE**: First you have to have `DOM` element in your script, unless you aren't aware of that `DOM` is already fully loaded. Nonetheless of `DOM` element position in your script you can write JavaScript as following:

```
window.onload = function(){
    // here goes your code
};
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because your canvas isn't in the DOM yet.

Wrap it in a `window.onload`

```
window.onload = function(){
   var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
   console.log(c);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your dom(`canvas`) is not ready for your script, put your code inside `window.onload`

```
 window.onload = function (){
    //this scripts runs when your canvas is ready  
    var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    console.log(c);
}
```